# Derivative step by step Algebra

Tags: derivatives

> What is the derivative of 
>   $f(x)=x\sqrt{x} - 3x$?

I'm a student (Freshman). I kind of got confused about the derivative. So I tried my best what i got is

$\sqrt{x} + \frac{x}{2 \sqrt{x}} - 3$

Please reply with step by step derivative.

Comment: Hint  $f (x )=x^{3/2}-3x $

Comment: Your solution is correct, just pay attention to the fact that $$\frac x{\sqrt x}=\sqrt x\implies f'(x)=\frac32\sqrt x-3$$

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = x^{3\over 2} - 3x$

So, $$f'(x) = (x^{3\over2})' - (3x)' = {3\over2}x^{{3\over2}-1}\; - 3$$
Therefore $$f'(x) = {3\over2}\sqrt{x} \;\;- 3$$

Comment: Thank you for the soulotion